# I can't acess my windows drive from Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, windows, mount, ntfs

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/hduser/D036F56236F54A4C: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1002,gid=1002,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/hduser/D036F56236F54A4C"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option
```

This error messages comes every time

Answer (score 0):

Muru is right, you can not fully access a NTFS drive that is used by Windows for either hibernation or FastBoot. Windows somehow locks the volume so that you can only mount it with Ubuntu in read-only-mode. Boot back into Windows and shut it down completely. If necessary, also disable the FastBoot option.